# How to concatenate JSON date with other function return value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I need help in concatenate other function return value into my HTTP GET call return data.
step 1: I write some function which returns let suppose 3(integer).
Step 2: I request HTTP GET call to 3rd party API which returns JSON let suppose

```
{"content": [{"id":3,"Name":"rahul","Pincode":402152}, {"id":2,"Name":"naveen", "Pincode":4012543}]}
```

I need to know that How can I get Name with reference to id.

```
       var request = require('request');

                request({
                    url: 'http://www.example.com',

                }, function(error, response, body) {
                    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        let dataIzo = JSON.parse(body);
                        let fullData = `${dataIzo["Content"][0]["Name"]}`;
                        console.log(fullData);

                    }else {
                        console.error(response.error);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log(fullData);
            }
```

Now How can i concatenate my function return value(Step 1) in place of [0] >>>let fullData = `${dataIzo["Content"][0]["Name"]}`;

So that I will get only those Names who have a id no. 3 which is the return  value from Step 1.

Thank you

Comment: u can use for loop or for each to loop thru the objects.

Comment: Use [Array#find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: can u plz show me via code I am new to javascript

Comment: but how can i add in between[0] and ["Name"]>>> fullData = ${dataIzo["Content"][0]["Name"]};